# When does a continuous function defined on a closed and bounded convex set has a fixed point?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, continuity, convex-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

For a function $f$ defined from a domain $K$ to itself, we have a point $x$ in $K$ is said to be a fixed point of $f$ if $f$ maps $x$ to itself. When
the domain K is a compact convex set with some additional properties we have theorems like Brouwer Fixed-Point
Theorem, Schauder Fixed-Point Theorem etc. which asserts the existence of a fixed point in $K$ for any continuous
function $f$ from $K$ to itself. I want to know when the domain $K$ (instead of compact set) is just a closed and bounded convex set, are there any results which gives the existence of a fixed point for a continuous function on $K$.
i.e., when does continuous functions defined on a closed and bounded convex set has a
fixed point?

Comment: So to clarify, you're not concerned with finite dimensional vector spaces over R or C where closed and bounded is equivalent to compact?

Comment: No, in a general space.